# c++ force method to be defined even though it is not inherited

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I have run into a problem in which I need a method to be defined for any types that inherit from a base class that I have created, yet I need that method to be static, is there anyway I can force it to be created?

The reason I need this I will have people be extending my base class, but I need to be able to guarantee a call to a function like so `derivedType derivedType::createFromSerialized(std::string)` will work to create a new instance from a serialization.

**Edit:** I am trying to follow  Richard J. Ross III's advice and use `static_assert` however I am running into some problems with that and I have a feeling its due to it being called from a templated class but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
template <typename indType> class population {
        static_assert(std::is_function<indType::createFromSerialized>::value, "message");
....
};
```

However that is giving me an error of `to refer to a type member of a template parameter, use ‘typename indType:: createFromSerialized’` and `no type named 'createFromSerialized' in 'class test'`

The reason I am trying to use `static_assert` is to get a nicer error message that will give information about the proper function signature for `createFromSerialized` instead of just one that says its not defined.

Comment: Using a `static_assert` seems like the most logical option.

Comment: who would be calling the derivedType::createFromSerialized() function? You need this call guaranteed?

Comment: it will be compiler/linker error if `derivedType derivedType::createFromSerialized(std::string)` is called anywhere without it defined

Comment: @Bryan Yes it would be an but it would not give any information about what the prototype of the static method should be g++ only states that createFromSerialized is not a member of your derived type. `static_assert` seems to be the best way of giving information about what the signature of the method should be

Comment: As a side note I have updated my question with some new problems related to trying @RichardJ.RossIII s way

Comment: In a template you don't check you can call a function, you just go ahead and call it anyway. If there's no such function, you will get an instantiation failure. The only thing `static_assert` can buy you is a slightly better error message.

Comment: That is all I'm trying for.

Comment: It's a valid desire, why don't you mention it in the question itself?

Comment: Ah my bad I thought I had it in there must have forgot to put it in

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by combining `static_assert` and SFINAE detection technique.

```
template<typename T, typename V = bool>
struct has_deserialize : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_deserialize<T,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<decltype(&T::createFromSerialized), 
                     T* (*)(const std::string&)>::value,
        bool
        >::type
    > : std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
class test
{
  static_assert(has_deserialize<T>::value, "No suitable createFromSerialized");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is possible through a factory pattern very easily. Not sure whether you can accomplish it using templates.

Here's a skeleton of how I would go about implementing the serialization functionality.

**SerializationFunctor.h**

```
class Base;

class SerializationFunctor
{
   virtual Base* operator(FILE* in) const = 0;
};
```

**Base.h**

```
class Base
{

   bool registerSerializationFunction(std::string const& identifier,
                                      SerializationFunctor* functor);
};
```

**ConcreteA.h**

```
class ConcreteA
{
};
```

**ASerializationFunctor.cc**

```
class ASerializationFunctor : public SerializationFunctor
{
   virtual Base* operator(FILE* in)
   {
      // Restore ConcreteA and return a pointer.
   }
};

bool dummy = registerSerializationFunction("ConcreteA", new ASerializationFunctor());
```

**ConcreteB.h**

```
class ConcreteB
{
};
```

**BSerializationFunctor.cc**

```
class BSerializationFunctor : public SerializationFunctor
{
   virtual Base* operator(FILE* in)
   {
      // Restore ConcreteB and return a pointer.
   }
};

bool dummy = registerSerializationFunction("ConcreteB", new BSerializationFunctor());
```